# Can not get gsub! and regex to work on my method

Tags: ruby, regex

Im working on an assignment, so please do not solve this straight up for me.
I need to take the `ugly_ouput` here which would be `=> 1x^3+-2x^2+3x^1+4x^0+` and make it `=> x^3-2x^2+3x+4`. I know that I need to use regex, but I cannot get my `make_pretty` method to cooperate. AT ALL. even trying to just find all the x's and replace them with y's is not working. Could you maybe point me to the right direction???

```
class Polynomials

def initialize coefficient
  @coefficient = coefficient
end

def ugly_output 
  exponent = @coefficient.length - 1

    @coefficient.each do |i|
      unless i == 0
        print "#{i}x^#{exponent}+"
        exponent -= 1
      end
    end

end

def make_pretty 
 # get rid of 0's, +-, and ^1 when they appear in output

  ugly_output.to_s.gsub!(/\+-/, "-")
end

end

#polynom = Polynomials.new [1, -2, 3, 4]
polynom = Polynomials.new [-3, -4, 1, 0, 6]


polynom.make_pretty
```

the rules for the assignment are:
-if a coefficient is `1`, it doesn't get printed
-if a coefficient is negative, you have to display something like `-2x^3`, not `+-2x^3`
-if a coefficient is `0`, nothing gets added to the output
-for `x^1` the `^1` part gets omitted
-`x^0 == 1`, so we don't need to display it

Comment: your ugly_output is directly printing the result, and what is printed, is printed, you can not change it later.

Comment: For is coefficient is `1`, check if `@coefficient` is `1`, just print without `i`. You don't need any kind of Regex.

Comment: @Meier, you are right. Edited: if you have read my comment, please ignore it.

Comment: I'm unsure why you'd use a regex when the original polynomial is generated by your program as well? Updating the generator's logic to incorporate rules is easier/preferred approach, imo.

Comment: @meier Could you expand on that a little more? If im not printing in my unless statement, what am I doing? `return` and `p` do not produce the output I need.

Comment: let your method create a string and return it, instead of printing it. In the loop, you  append to the string. Then do the print outside of the method.

Comment: cool. I added `@ugly_polynom = String.new` to my `initialize` and then appended everything to that variable in `ugly_output`. works like a charm. Thanks alot!!

Comment: check out [rubular](http://rubular.com/). I use it all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all - I'm not in to ruby but when I google ruby and `gsub/gsub!` it looks like you should be using `gsub`  - not `gsub!` - in this case.

And (describing this in some sort of meta language ;) I solved this using one regex replacing either of your conditions with nothing, i.e.

```
 gsub(regex, "")
```

where regex is

```
 cond1 | cond2 | cond3 | cond4 | cond5
```

You've already touched on one of the conditions - `+-`. To just match the `+` and keep the `-` you'll have to use lookahead. This is done like

```
\+(?=-)
```

which matches the (quoted) `+` and ensures that it's followed by a `-`. Replacing this with `""` removes the `+` and **keeps** the `-`.

Then add the other conditions (Cn) in a similar way and you'll end up with something like

```
ugly_output.to_s.gsub(/\+(?=-)|C2|C3|C4|C5/, "")
```

This is where you'll do your work ;)

Hope this is helpful to you.

Edit:

On Cary's point (in a comment), `\b` is your friend here. It ensures that there's a *word* boundary adjacent. I.e. if you test for a boundary and then a digit, it ensures that digit is preceded by something else than a word character (which includes digits). To spell it out - `\b1` matches `+1` but not `+21`.

Regards.

Comment: I know you don't want to be too specific about the regex, but you may want to say something about distinguishing between ``1x` and `21x` and between `0x` and `30x` (and in exponents). Also, there is the option of treating `+-` with a separate `gsub`, in which case the lookahead is not needed.

Comment: @CarySwoveland First - Nathan... **Don't cheat**! ;) To anyone interested in my actual solution, with the added cases of Cary's *challange*, here's a regex101 of how I did it. [Don't look here, Nathan](https://regex101.com/r/cP0iP0/3)

Comment: @CarySwoveland Additionally, you could of course split this in to five different `gsub`'s. In fact, that probably would improve readability.

Comment: @ClassG: Thanks a lot. I didnt really know what you meant by `\b` so I looked. I had something very very similar, which made me very happy. I also added `x(?=\^1` too to make anything that was `1x^2` `x^2` instead.
thansk for your help!!!